# Hide relationship laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have this controller, with 2 relationships: groups and group making a joing

```
 public function find($name){
        $locate= Products::where('name', 'like', "$name%")->with('groups.group')->get();

        return response()->json($locate, 200);
    }
```

With returns me this:

```
   [{
       "name":"Test",
       "code":"123",
       "price":"321.00",
       "created_at":null,
       "updated_at":null,
       "groups":{
        "id":1,
        "product_id":1,
        "group_id":2,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "group":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"Test",
         "desc":"dasdasdsa",
         "commission_s":2,
         "commission_m":2,
         "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null
}}}]
```

The big problem is, i dont whant the "groups" object, its just a relational table.

The models:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'code', 'price'];

    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public function Groups()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\pGroup', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Pgroup model

```
class pGroup extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['group_id', 'product_id'];

    public function Group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductGroup');
    }
}
```

Comment: Then just remove `->with('groups.group')`

Comment: No, brother, theres two objects "groups" and "group" i dont need to see the "groups" in json, because its just a relational table.it doenst make sense to show it

Comment: Why do you call it groups when you have only one per product? Why don't you simply call it group, and then use `->with('group')`

Comment: If I call this, it will show me the relational table, which contains only foreign keys. I want to access the "group_id" and take some infos from table ProductGroup, which contains name, description etc.

Comment: Then you structure is wrong. You use many to many when you need one to many. Instead of using the middle table which is `ProductGroup` you can just use, `products` and `group`, and then in the `products` table you will have `group_id` which will be the `id` of the `groups` table. And you will use foreign key for better performance.

This means one Group -> many products

Comment: I cant add `group_id` inside the `products`, because the products may or may not have a group, it is optional

Comment: you can always make it `nullable`

Comment: is this right? I am using a relational table to avoid this

Comment: If you need to have a Many to Many relationship between products and groups, which means one product can have many groups and one group can have many products then your usage is correct. Otherwise there is no point of using middle table and you can use nullable field with foreign key.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That helps.